# Join 2 dataframes and create Parent Child Relationship?

Tags: python, pandas

i have 2 dataframes parent and child, i want to concatenate both in groupby manner

df_parent

```
           parent  parent_value
    0   Super Sun             0
    1  Alpha Mars             4
    2       Pluto             9
```

df_child

```
                   child  value
    0         Planet Sun    100
    1  one Sun direction    101
    2     Ice Pluto Tune    101
    3       Life on Mars     99
    4         Mars Robot    105
    5          Sun Twins    200
```

I want the ouput to be in order `order = ['Sun', 'Pluto', 'Mars']`

```
Sun
-childs
Pluto
-childs
Mards
-childs
```

I want to find the child with keyword wise, refer `parent_dict`

```
parent_dict = {'Super Sun': 'Sun',
           'Alpha Mars': 'Mars',
           'Pluto': 'Pluto'}
```

expected output

```
    child         value
0   Super Sun             0 # parent
1   Planet Sun          100 # child  
2   one Sun direction   101 # child   
3   Sun Twins           200 # child  
4   Pluto                 9 # parent
5   Ice Pluto Tune      101 # child       
6   Alpha Mars            4 # parent
7   Life on Mars         99 # child    
8   Mars Robot          105 # child
```

So far i have tried to iterate master list and both dfs, but expected output is not coming, here is my code

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
for o in order:
    key = o
    for j, row in df_parent.iterrows():
        if key in row[0]:
            output_df.at[j, 'parent'] = key
            output_df.at[j, 'value'] = row[1]
            for k, row1 in df_child.iterrows():
                if key in row1[0]:
                    output_df.at[j, 'parent'] = key
                    output_df.at[j, 'value'] = row[1]              

print(output_df)
```

Output:

```
  parent  value
0    Sun    0.0
2  Pluto    9.0
1   Mars    4.0
```

Comment: ok, I think the problem lies here `output_df.at[j, 'parent'] = key` instead of incrementing index, I am overwriting it with`j` variable, I might need to maintain a separate counter

Comment: @jezrael help me on this, is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `append` with both dataframe after some preparation. First create a column keyword in both `df_parent` and `df_child` used for sorting later. To do so, you an use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) such as:

```
import pandas as pd
order = ['Sun', 'Pluto', 'Mars']
condlist_parent = [df_parent['parent'].str.contains(word) for word in order]
df_parent['keyword'] = pd.np.select(condlist = condlist_parent, choicelist = order, default = None)
condlist_child = [df_child['child'].str.contains(word) for word in order]
df_child['keyword'] = pd.np.select(condlist = condlist_child, choicelist = order, default = None)
```

giving for example for `df_parent`:

```
       parent  parent_value keyword
0   Super Sun             0     Sun
1  Alpha Mars             4    Mars
2       Pluto             9   Pluto
```

Now you can use `append` and also [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) to order the dataframe according to the list `order`. The `rename` is used to fit your expected output and for the `append` working as wanted (columns should have the same name in both dataframe).

```
df_all = (df_parent.rename(columns={'parent':'child','parent_value':'value'})
                     .append(df_child,ignore_index=True))
# to order the column keyword with the list order
df_all['keyword'] = pd.Categorical(df_all['keyword'], ordered=True, categories=order)
# now sort_values by the column keyword, reset_index and drop the column keyword
df_output = (df_all.sort_values('keyword')
                  .reset_index(drop=True).drop('keyword',1)) # last two methods are for cosmetic
```

The output is then:

```
               child  value
0          Super Sun      0
1         Planet Sun    100
2  one Sun direction    101
3          Sun Twins    200
4              Pluto      9
5     Ice Pluto Tune    101
6         Alpha Mars      4
7       Life on Mars     99
8         Mars Robot    105
```

Note: The fact that the parents are before childs after sorting on 'keyword' is that `df_child` is appened to `df_parent`, and not in the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, by iterating both dataframes, but this seems a very very long procedure

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
c = 0
for o in order:
    key = o
    for j, row in df_parent.iterrows():
        if key in row[0]:
            output_df.at[c, 'parent'] = row[0]
            output_df.at[c, 'value'] = row[1]
            c += 1
            for k, row1 in df_child.iterrows():
                if key in row1[0]:
                    output_df.at[c, 'parent'] = row1[0]
                    output_df.at[c, 'value'] = row1[1]              
                    c += 1
```

Output:

```
              parent  value
0          Super Sun    0.0
1         Planet Sun  100.0
2  one Sun direction  101.0
3          Sun Twins  200.0
4              Pluto    9.0
5     Ice Pluto Tune  101.0
6         Alpha Mars    4.0
7       Life on Mars   99.0
8         Mars Robot  105.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider concatenating both dataframes and order by a *keyword* find:

```
order = ['Sun', 'Pluto', 'Mars']

def find_keyword(str_param):    
    output = None
    # ITERATE THROUGH LIST AND RETURN MATCHING POSITION
    for i,v in enumerate(order):
        if v in str_param:
            output = i

    return output

# RENAME COLS AND CONCAT DFs
df_combined = pd.concat([df_parent.rename(columns={'parent':'item', 'parent_value':'value'}),
                         df_child.rename(columns={'child':'item'})],
                        ignore_index=True)

# CREATE KEYWORD COL WITH DEFINED FUNCTION
df_combined['keyword'] = df_combined['item'].apply(find_keyword)

# SORT BY KEYWORD AND DROP HELPER COL
df_combined = df_combined.sort_values(['keyword', 'value'])\
                         .drop(columns=['keyword']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_combined)
#                 item  value
# 0          Super Sun      0
# 1         Planet Sun    100
# 2  one Sun direction    101
# 3          Sun Twins    200
# 4              Pluto      9
# 5     Ice Pluto Tune    101
# 6         Alpha Mars      4
# 7       Life on Mars     99
# 8         Mars Robot    105
```